# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='fieldname3_1']"}

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Wanted to locate an element with python selenium 4.
My code:

```
x = s.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='fieldname3_1']")
```

https://thearbacademy.com/arbitrage-betting-calculator/

link for page

[image: Trying to locate this]

The HTML looks like

```
<input aria-label="" id="fieldname3_1" name="fieldname3_1" class="field number large valid" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="false">
```

My error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='fieldname3_1']"}
```

Comment: Try `//*[@id="fieldname3_1"]` (with the asterisk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `id` value, also use `WebDriveWait` for the elements to load.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'fieldname2_1')))
#myElem.send_keys("123")
```